# If I had more money!

Tags: grammar, subjunctives

Generally speaking, ellipsis of the resulting clause is required in the use of "if only...". For this reason, the sentence #1 below will be easily accepted. On the other hand, the sentence #2 is usually not permitted despite its logical meaning is similar to #1. Therefore, I would like to check the acceptability of #2.

1. If only I had more money!
2. If I had more money!

Comment: The second sentence is incomplete. The first is complete.

Comment: There is no resulting clause.

Answer (score 1):

Number two is incomplete - it is a sentence fragment. To correct it, you need to have an **independent clause** added to the **subordinate clause** that it already is. For example:

If I had more money (subordinate), I would buy that book (independent).

Number one is also not a proper sentence, but of course people still use it - English speakers don't use proper grammar anyway :)

It can be corrected in the same way as number two; but it will be accepted on its own.